# countdown timer with react useEffect skip one second on windows local, but not on online code editor like codepen, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's just a super simple countdown timer using react(v.18) useEffect hook, the bug is, on windows localhost it always skips the second second: for example when it starts from 10s down, it skips the 9s, (10s, 8s, 7s, 6s, 5s, 4s, 3s, 2s, 1s, 0s...), from 100s down, it skips the 99s(100s, 98s, 97s...0s)...

What I don't understand is, the bug stays only on browsers on windows, but when I try the same code on an online code editor like codepen with react (v. 16), the countdown runs perfectly without this bug.

where the problem could be?

```js
function App() {
  
  const[timeRemaining, setTimeRemaining] = useState(10)

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      timeRemaining > 0 &&
        setTimeRemaining(time => time - 1)
    }, 1000)
}, [timeRemaining])
  
  
  return (
    <div className="App">          
       <h4>Time remaining: {timeRemaining} </h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setTimeout` and passing `timeRemaining` to the `useEffect` to retrigger it every `1000ms`, use `setInterval` and the callback provided to `setTimeRemaining` to access the most current value.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Run every 1000ms, without needing to rely on a re-render.
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        // currentTime is what the current value is.
        setTimeRemaining(currentTime => {
            // If the current time is 0, then stop the interval and return 0.
            if(currentTime <= 0){
                clearInterval(interval);
                return 0;
            }

            return currentTime - 1;
        });
    }, 1000);


    // Ensure you clear the interval on dismount.
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply, the code works perfectly. I thought of using setInterval() at the beginning since it's the classic way for timer function, but then I thought if setTimeout can reach the goal, it would be also nice because it can save few lines of code, but obvioubly I was wrong, seems there is no shortcut in this:-)